# Gatsby Contentful embedded image

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-image, raw

As I see there is no json option anymore when querying the contentfulBlogPost only raw. I was able to make some changes to get everything from the body, except the image from that post.

If I made a test in GraphQL Playground I can get the image id and url but that's it.

```
query {
  allContentfulAsset {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        file {
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to find an example how to get embedded images but no luck....

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { documentToReactComponents } from '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer'

import Layout from '../components/layout'


export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    contentfulBlogPost(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
      title
      publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
      body {
        raw 
      }
    }
    allContentfulAsset {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          file {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const Blog = (props) => {
  const options = {
    renderNode: {
      "embedded-asset-block": (node) => {
        const alt = node.data.title
        const url = node.file.url
        return <img alt={alt} src={url}/>
      }
    }
  }
  return (
        <Layout>
          <h1>{props.data.contentfulBlogPost.title}</h1>
          <p>{props.data.contentfulBlogPost.publishedDate}</p>
          {documentToReactComponents(JSON.parse(props.data.contentfulBlogPost.body.raw, options))}
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Blog
```

Plugins:

```
...
 'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve:   'gatsby-transformer-remark',
      options: {
        plugins: [
          'gatsby-remark-relative-images',
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images-contentful',
            options: {
              maxWidth: 750,
              linkImagesToOriginal: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }

    }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Hi I saw this solution in a Youtube comment. First thing you have to do is change your Graphql query to something like this:

```
    query ($slug: String!) {
      contentfulBlogPost(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
         id
         title
         publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
         body {
            raw
            references {
               ... on ContentfulAsset {
                  contentful_id
                  title
                  file {
                     url
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Then change your `options` constant to:

```
    const options = {
      renderNode: {
         [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
            console.log(node);
            const imageID = node.data.target.sys.id;
            const {
               file: {url}, 
               title
            } = props.data.contentfulBlogPost.body.references.find(({contentful_id: id}) => id === imageID);

            return <img src={url} alt={title} />
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
​
const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>
​
const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </>
      )
    },
  },
}
​
renderRichText(node.bodyRichText, options)
```

*Source: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/*

The `return` statement in `BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET` entry will contain your data, adapt to your needs. If you go inside the dependency, you'll see all the exposed methods, so you will have also a `BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY` entry for your embedded entries. Apply it like:

```
[BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: node => {
  // your logic to manipulate the entry here
  return (
    <>
      <div>whatever</div>
    </>
  )
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is still struggling to find the "references" field in graphql, remember that you HAVE TO first create an entry in contentful by adding at least one image. Otherwise, the references field will not show up in graphql, hence you can not query it.